# How is a SSL certificate affected if the same domain is being hosted on 2 separate servers whilst DNS propagation is occurring?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

Is there a way to mitigate any issues? What should I consider when migrating servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as both servers have a valid certificate for the domain (even the exact same one on both), and so long as everyone is still accessing the site via the domain name (i.e. going to example.com as opposed to 123.123.123.123), the SSL certificate is not affected, and neither is the user experience.

In fact, hosting your site on two different servers, each with the same certificate, while awaiting the DNS change to move from one to the other is probably the most transparent and user-friendly way to migrate servers -- 99.9% of your users simply will not know the difference (provided there's no errors or anything on the new server, of course).

Comment: Thanks. Odd I had read somewhere that you couldn't do so. Am trying to find that very same article. Anyhoo, does this mean that even if go back to same vendor that I had purchased the SSL certificate from for the same domain, it would not be an issue. Secondly does the SSL authentication not get fed back to the Certificate Authority?

Comment: Here is an article I came across http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-467832.html.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey The key part is what your clients use to connect to  your service. If they're using IP, then probably not. If they're using a FQDN, it should work *just fine*.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey The simplest solution is to just copy the certificate you have already put on your first server over to your second -- no need to buy a new one (assuming, as sysadmin1138 points out, your users are using the FQDN). If you do, for whatever reason, decide to buy a new certificate for the second server, you can buy it from any vendor -- no need to go back to the same one. As far as the CA is concerned, they've approved the certificate, not the server per se, so moving it around to a different server doesn't need to go back to them at all.

Comment: @sysadmin1138/Kromey  - Thanks. So I can assume safely that the certificate is bound to the FQDN and not an IP address unless I have specifically bought the SSL certificate for an IP address?

Comment: As far as that article is concerned, "Website Rob" is just flat *wrong*. No two ways about it. I have personally moved certificates from one server to another with no problems (same FQDN). I have copied certificates from one server to a second (and third) load-balanced server all serving a single FQDN, with no problems. In fact, at one point I had a *single* SSL certificate securing the connections to no fewer than **5** individual servers representing 3 different IPs all operating the same FQDN. At no point did any browser complain that the IP changed, nor did we have change the cert at all.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Exactly. The short version is that an SSL certificate is bound to the FQDN, and the IP address is irrelevant. Similarly, the *number* of servers and IP addresses is likewise irrelevant.